# method without access modifier

Tags: c#, .net, encapsulation

Ok this is bugging me.. I know I've read it somewhere and google isn't helping.

What is the accessibility level of a method that does not specify an access modifier?

```
void Foo()
{
    //code
}
```

I want to say `internal` but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The default accessibility for a **type** is `internal`, but the default accesibility of that type's **members** depends on the type.

Generally speaking, members of a **class** are `private` by default, where as members of a **struct** are `public` by default.  This varies by language; default struct access modifiers for C++ are public, where as for C#, they are private.

Comment: Are you guys sure about this downvote?  If I place a method in a C# class, with no access modifier, the C# 3.0 compiler builds it as a private method.

Comment: Steve is correct.  The default accessibility for class methods is `private`.  Try it for yourself.

Comment: This answer is correct.  Just verified it in VS2010 because I originally thought it was wrong too.

Comment: Members of a `struct` are `public` by default in C++, but according to the MSDN page linked from several other answers, members of a `struct` are `private` by default in C#.

Comment: -1 because two authoritative references say members of a `struct` are `private` by default in C#.  (MSDN is one, and *The C# Programming Language, 3rd Ed.* is the other.)

Comment: Default accessibility for member variables either for struct or class is private by default if not mentioned. Here is the MSDN link supporting the same. It is evident in second paragraph of "Class and Struct accessibility" section :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

Answer (score 24):

Assuming this is a C# method, since you have the ".net" tag.

People need to differentiate between "member" accessibility and "class" accessibility.

- The default accessibility of class members (including methods) in C# is private. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2(v=vs.140).aspx
- The default accessibility of a class itself is internal.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, `internal` is the default for classes, but `private` is the default for members.

Answer (score 12):

For a class: Internal is the default if no access modifier is specified.

For a method: Private is the default if no access modifier is specified.

Answer (score 8):

From *The C# Programming Language, Third Edition* by Anders Hejlsberg *et al*, section 10.3.5 ("Class Members - Access Modifiers") on page 434:

> A *class-member-declaration* can have any one of the five possible kinds of declared accessibility (§3.5.1): `public`, `protected internal`, `protected`, `internal`, or `private`.  Except for the `protected internal` combination, it is a compile-time error to specify more than one access modifier.  **When a *class-member-declaration* does not include any access modifiers, `private` is assumed.** [Emphasis mine]

And then in section 11.2 ("Struct Members") on page 539:

> Except for the differences noted in §11.3, the descriptions of class members provided in §10.3 through §10.14 apply to struct members as well.

Section 11.3 does not mention anything about access modifiers, so my reading of this implies that members of a `struct` without an access modifier are also `private` by default.  This corresponds with [what MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx) and with my own experience.

Answer (score 5):

Oh wait, there's one more thing ....

`interface` method declarations are of course `public` by definition. So the following implementation is `public`, without an explicit access modifier.

```
public class MyClass : IEqualityComparer<MyClass>
    bool IEqualityComparer<MyClass>.Equals(MyClass x , MyClass y) {}
}
```

Comment: btw interface methods cannot be private

Comment: oh, yeah... [Inheriting `EqualityComparer` is recommended, not implementing the interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). see "Remarks"

Answer (score 0):

Class methods are private and sealed by default in .NET. 
This means the method is only visible within the class and cannot be overridden by the inherited class.

Answer (score 0):

hope this clarifies all as per screenshot directly from MSDN

[image]