# How to define a method following top-level statements

Tags: c#, methods, toplevel-statement

I recently updated Visual Studio and found out about this new feature (to me it is new) of top-level statements.

As I understand it, the compiler completes the definitions for the `Program` class and `Main` method, without you having to explicitly type it up.

This is useful, but I'm having trouble when defining a new method. I would like a method in the `Program` class. And call this with a top-level statement. Here is some example code:

```
Console.WriteLine("toplevel");
ThisShouldBeAMethodOfProgramClass();

public static void ThisShouldBeAMethodOfProgramClass()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Static in Program class");
}
```

This is giving me build errors, because the public static modifiers are not valid. I think it interprets this as a local function in `Main`. I can remove the modifiers, but this is just example code, my real code has more methods and classes.

How can I do this? Should I not use top-level for this?

I would like this to effectively be the same as:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("toplevel");
        ThisShouldBeAMethodOfProgramClass();
    }
    public static void ThisShouldBeAMethodOfProgramClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Static in Program class");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can keep using top-level statements and append additional members with a partial Program class.

```
using System;
Console.WriteLine("toplevel");
ThisShouldBeAMethodOfProgramClass();

public static partial class Program
{
    public static void ThisShouldBeAMethodOfProgramClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Static in Program class");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Or just remove the access modifier: [method without access modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917495/method-without-access-modifier)

```cs
using System;
Console.WriteLine("toplevel");
ThisShouldBeAMethodOfProgramClass();

static void ThisShouldBeAMethodOfProgramClass()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Static in Program class");
}
```

Update: as per the comment by [@shingo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6196568/shingo), it's not a method without an access modifier which leads to a public method implicitly, but a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) in the invisible `Main()` method scope which prevents you from invoking it from outside of the file(the whole file with [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements) is inside the `Main()`).

So all the above is identify with following:

```cs
using System;

namespace Program
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("toplevel");
            ThisShouldBeAMethodOfProgramClass();

            static void ThisShouldBeAMethodOfProgramClass()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Static in Program class");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite right, this `ThisShouldBeAMethodOfProgramClass` method is just a local method that cannot be accessed by other code.

Comment: [You are right](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKzATgAoAiYAewAcAbAUwDc6bSBKAbjwBUALASwDOAZR4UINOACE6AQQCydYKLgB5AGYEA7AGEaAQwEDiHPHgIA2AASoALJd6CRYidPmLl6rboNHWeAN54lsHWRGRCwHrAfADGlnxQoZrW6GycuAC+pvgAzCmWKkp0YAFBIah5tpYAIhTGlgC8AHz2/MKi4lKyCkoUqhqYOvqGxukZQA), but he might just use the method `ThisShouldBeAMethodOfProgramClass()` only for one time.

Answer (score 0):

Top-level statements such as entry point or main() function but there are some notes between them

You can use methods in the Top-level statement in this way:

```
DisplayMessage();

static void DisplayMessage()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcom in Top-Level Statement");
}
```

Top-level statements enable quick experimentation and beginner tutorials.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).