# How do I add a working Main method to a dotnet 6 console application to access command line arguments?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a c# console application where I need to take some command line arguments.

For this reason I need a main method, instead of the non-main method that is currently there, and since I can't find any material on how to do it without.

So, I tried just pasting some code into my newly created visual studio dotnet 6 c# application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("hi there");

}
```

Which does'nt work. The code is not executed.
How do I add a main method, so I can take some cmd arguments?

Comment: The app is terminating so you are not seeing the message.  Add a Console.ReadLine() at end of code so app does not terminate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a method following top-level statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72160360/how-to-define-a-method-following-top-level-statements)

Answer (score 8):

**You don't need a classic Main method to access command-line arguments.** You can just access the "magic" variable `args`. The following is a complete and valid C# program ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6ynmxS)):

```
using System;

Console.WriteLine("I got " + args.Length + " command line arguments.");
```

This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements):

> You don't declare an `args` variable. For the single source file that contains your top-level statements, the compiler recognizes `args` to mean the command-line arguments. The type of `args` is a `string[]`, as in all C# programs.

---

For completeness: If you want a "classic" `Main` entry point, you need

- a class or struct with
- a static method called `Main` with
- a return type of either `void` or `int` (or `Task`/`Task<int>`, if you create an `async` method) and
- no parameter or a single `string[]` parameter.

It seems like you miss the class in your example. A full minimal working example looks like this:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

The exact criteria are documented here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line

Answer (score 1):

When you create the project, there is a box to check to not use top-level statements. Create a new project and check that box, then it will work just like in older versions. The box even has an info icon next to it that, when moused-over displays this message:

> Whether to generate an explicit Program class and Main method instead of top-level statements.

If you do create a project with top-level statements, [this URL](https://aka.ms/new-console-template) is provided at the top of the code file. The information you needed was provided but you didn't pay attention. It's always important to pay attention to what VS is trying to tell you because it provides a lot of useful information.